# Rearrange Variables in an equation with Ruby

Tags: ruby

(To begin with, I am a beginner in Ruby.)

I want to rearrange variables in a linear equation (there may be 2 or more variables).

I have an equation

```
a + 2*b - 1 = 0
```

I would like Ruby to give me

```
a = 1 - 2*b
```

Or alternatively

```
b = (1-a)/2
```

Is there a way to do this in Ruby ? (It is possible in Matlab, which, in my case, seems overkill...)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You completely misunderstand the difference between programming languages and tools. Ruby won’t do anything for you, save for executing your own code.

Comment: There might be some Ruby symbolic math libs.

Comment: @mudasobwa : I understand that, and you are right, but if a tool exist (symbolic gem), I wish to try it, especially if it has been written in Ruby...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [symbolic](http://brainopia.github.io/symbolic/) gem.

It should provide you with the tools you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall try that.